# Why does my program freeze when ever I hit the login button

Tags: javascript, local-storage

so I have this program that makes it so you can password protect bookmarks by putting it as a link and saving it in localStorage. The thing is when I hit the login button (which checks if you have the correct username and password) and have the correct username and password the program freezes and I can't figure out why. the localStorage.getItem('number') is set to 0.

```js
function increment() {
  var num = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('number'), 10);
  num++;
  localStorage.setItem('number', num.toString());
  return num.toString();
}

function read() {
    return localStorage.getItem('number');
}

function registerScreen() {
    $("body").html("<input id='u2' autocomplete='off' placeholder='username'><br><input id='p2' type='password' autocomplete='off' placeholder='password'><br><button onclick='register()'>create account</button>")
    var num = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('number'), 10);
    for (var i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
        localStorage.removeItem(i.toString());
    }
    localStorage.setItem('number', '0')

}

function loginScreen() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('password') == null || localStorage.getItem('username') == null) {
        alert("you do not seem to have an account")
        registerScreen();
    }
    $("body").html("<input id='u' autocomplete='off' placeholder='username'><br><input id='p'type='password' autocomplete='off' placeholder='password'><br><button onclick='login()'>login</button>")
}

function login() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('username') === $('#u').val() && localStorage.getItem('password') === $('#p').val()) {
        $("body").html("<h1>Hello " + localStorage.getItem('username') + " </h1><br><button onclick='add()'>add a bookmark</button>")
        place();
    }
}

function register() {
    localStorage.setItem('username', $("#u2").val())
    localStorage.setItem('password', $("#p2").val())
    $("body").html("<h1>Hello " + localStorage.getItem('username') + "</h1><br><button onclick='add()'>add a bookmark</button>")
}

function add() {
    var word = prompt("What would you like to see as your link");
    var href = prompt("where would you like to have the link to go");
    var a = "<a href='https://" + href + "' target='_blank'>" + word + "</a>";
    $("body").append(a + "<br>")
    localStorage.setItem(increment(), a.toString());
}

function place() {
    var x = parseInt(read(), 10);
    for (var i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
        $("body").append(localStorage.getItem(i.toString()) + "<br>");
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="loginScreen()">login</button>
<button onclick="registerScreen()">register</button>
```

Comment: What's the point of calling `register()` if it immediately overwrites the body with something else?

Comment: @Barmar - I hit send before reading your comment :p

Comment: @Bravo But the functions will still be in memory, so that doesn't matter.

Comment: Nothing ever calls the `login()` function, so I guess it's irrelevant.

Comment: @Barmar - we can't see how any of those functions are called ... sure, register is called by login, but login is never called, place is called by x, but where is x called? without seeing the initial state of HTML, how can we know any of those functions can be called :p

Comment: It's especially confusing that the `login()` function adds a new `login` button, but that button runs `x()` instead of `login()`.

Comment: Your `place()` function has as its termination condition `i <= parseInt(n(), 10)`, but `n()`, every time it is called, gets a number out of local storage, adds one to it, sets the new number in local storage and returns the incremented number. So `i` will never catch up to `n()`, so you have an infinite loop.

Comment: all you need is `else` just before `$("body").html("<input id='u' placeholder='username'><br><input id='p'type='password' placeholder='password'><br><button onclick='x()'>login</button>")` in `login` and it will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an infinite loop here:

```
  for (var i = 0; i <= parseInt(n(), 10); i++) {
    $("body").append(localStorage.getItem(i.toString()));
  }
```

Every time you call `n()` it fetches the `number` item from localStorage and increments it. So each time through the loop, `n()` returns a higher number, and `i` will never catch up to it.

You should just call `n()` once.

```
let count = parseInt(n(), 10);
for (let i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
  $("#body").append(localStorage.getItem(i.toString());
}
```

I'm also not sure why you're incrementing the number in `n()`. You should only do that when you're saving a new item, not when you're just reading them.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get out any bugs I saw in the program. If you wish to try the program out here is the [link](https://liveweave.com/JQ9Hsi/demo)