# How do you bind using a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

When clicking the buttons that have the class of folder (Which is all of them that are created by the addf function (not stated in this question as some people said the original program was irrelevant)) are not responding to being clicked. I have the alert to test if the event is even being called. It isnt.

```
        $('.folder').click(function() {
      alert('works')
        fnum = $(this).attr(id);
        $('body').html("<button class='btn btn-submit' onclick='addb()'>add a bookmark</button>")
        $('body').append(localStorage.getItem(fnum + 'b'));
    })
```

Comment: Please remove anything that is not directly related to the problem -> [mcve]

Comment: Apart from what @Andreas said, there is at least one typo: In `addf` you've written `$('body').apppend(folders + "<br>")` - remove a single "p" from `.append`.

Comment: thank you. I addressed both of your concerns

Comment: `.bind()` is deprecated. It is superseded by `.on()`.

Comment: `.html()` will destroy any previous content, so only the last iteration of the loop will determine its effect.

Comment: `a` will not be what you expect in the click handler. Use `let` instead of `var` to avoid that.

Comment: Don't use `id` attributes with sequential suffix numbers. Instead use the  `class` attribute (without that suffix).

Comment: but the way I have the rest of the website programmed if I don't use the id it will break as it would be really hard for me to put classes in something I can't read. I can't read it because I have the website programmed so it is fully user intractable

Comment: I tried the class thing. it doesn't work.

Comment: I have figured out why the buttons don't work. If you append an element the jQuery selectors don't do anything with regard to the appended elements.

Comment: I will send you a [link](https://liveweave.com/hOBHKH) to illustrate my point

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `html` method, just append the new elements in order to prevent removing event listeners. Also, you can just use `on` instead of `bind` since it has been deprecated. If you really need event delegation, you can use:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.f', callback);
```

I did not understand your use of the localStorage but if you need it please explain it further in the comments.

I removed the ids and loop in favor of classes since it makes easier to work with multiple elements.

```js
function addb () { console.log('click') };

$('.f').on('click', function() {
  var button = $('<button>add a bookmark</button>');
  button.addClass('btn btn-submit');
  button.on('click', addb);
  $('body').append(button);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="f">Button class 'f'</button>
```

Comment: I have the local storage because it is a website that allows me to password protect bookmarks. I used local storage because I don't have access to a server. if you are interested I shall have a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59002924/why-does-my-program-freeze-when-ever-i-hit-the-login-button?noredirect=1#comment104256428_59002924) to the other stack overflow page in which people helped me with the program. I changed it because I am adding folders